# setting a public web server by python3 http.server module

Tags: python, http, web, module, python-3.x

I new to python, as well as web developing.
I made a python web application with the help of http.server module and ran it on localhost port. It is working fine at localhost:abcd .

Now I want to run it on some public server like pythonanywhere or heroku! But the don't get the part what the server address and port would be.

I need help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On PythonAnywhere, you get a web application at your-username.pythonanywhere.com, running on port 80 -- so you just need to type http://your-username.pythonanywhere.com/ into your browser URL bar to access it.